# Fast application to move a selection of images

Tags: file-management

I have to sort some images in groups, in fact to classify some images for training a classifier based on Bag of Words. Instead of verify each image and move it manually, is there an application that does this "move to specific folder" based on some tag? Something like this:

[image]

And if I'll select one it will become green. At the end the green ones will be moved to one folder.

Different colours for different "move to folder" would be faster, but it will be good also just for one type and I will run it more than once. I think it is faster than just do it manually.

If not I'll try to do it my own, but in the future. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: What's wrong with keeping "CTRL" pressed when selecting, and dragging at the end? Is pressing CTRL too cumbersome? Or does the dragging take too much time?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: The photos are on a server and there is no thumbnail view, so opening every image and drag it to wanted folder is slow in my opinion.

Comment: So any image viewer with thumbnail and drag/drop capabilities will do?

Comment: No, I need some kind of semi-automatic thing, otherwise it's not an improvement.

Comment: `the photos are on a server`: What kind of server? FTP? It is very important to tell us that, otherwise we can't help you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add tags to the images, possibly exif, and then you can filter on the tags. This can be done in tools like:

- [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/)
- [Digicam](http://www.digikam.org) *also allows you to add coloured labels to images.*
- Gwenview
- Many others

I would suggest digiKam as you can add the labels &/or tags then use the filter(s) select all the images within the filter and then move/copy them to the required location.

Example view with filter panel:
[image]

Comment: Does it allow fast tagging (create tags; click photo->chose tag from pop-up list)?

Comment: Yes, with a frequently used tags, just right click and you can even add keyboard short cuts to specific tags if you like.

Comment: New comment from asker: `The photos are on a server`

Comment: Obviously to be able to manipulate tags the OP will need **write access** to the server but since they also mention *moving the files* I think that it is a reasonable assumption to make that they have it.

Comment: I have those rights, but how to access that folder on the server?

Comment: The same way that you normally would, e.g. mount the file system, etc., then Import->Add Folder seems like the best bet.