# Browsing and moving/saving photos

Tags: file-management

***The environment:***

I'm a Windows 7 user, have 2 monitors and very little knowledge of the pixel world. I have image & movie  files (JPEG & MP4) saved all together in an unorganized folder. Or at least, only auto-organized. (picture name & date are sorted by ascending order) Taken from a GoPro camera, they just count from x to x+1.

***The problem:***

I take a thousand pictures and enjoy 100 of them. I need a way to separates the ones I like in a different folder

***What i'm looking for:***

Is there a software or something I could do with my current settings to do that easily? I would like to, say, look at every picture one by one, and then press a shortcut or a button with my mouse (hopefully keyboard) that would separate this picture from the others.

***What i've done, without real success:***

I've looked into ways of "marking" it somehow (and then just sort the folder) but I couldn't find anything.
I haven't really seen anything helpful in the classic "Preview" software windows offers
I usually have one picture on the screen and the folder on the other, then i just look up the name and move the file manually. This takes forever as you can imagine.

Any idea ?

Comment: Related (about renaming pics): http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/a-program-to-sort-and-rename-photos-drag-drop

Comment: Related (about tagging as a possible solution): http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7311/fast-application-to-move-a-selection-of-images

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This is a workaround and is hardly optimal. I'm hoping someone else would post a better solution since I'm also interested in this question</sub>

I use a combination of [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) and [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/).

IrfanView allows you to rename the picture you are viewing by hitting <kbd>F2</kbd>, and AutoHotKey lets you assign hotkey to any key combination you like. I use a script that has this line in it:

```
#s::Send {F2}{Home}0000{Enter}
```

Whenever I encounter a picture I want to separate from the rest, I hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and the script simulates renaming the file to automatically prepend `0000`. After you're done browsing, you could just sort the files by name and all the renamed ones would show in the beginning.

After you copy/move the files, and if you mind that they had been renamed, you could use a [batch renaming tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11389/6834) to change them back by removing the first 4 characters of every file name.